# android app, get facebook user like info

Tags: android, facebook

I have a simple app in which the user logs in Facebook.

How do i get access to the pages that the user liked? I specifically want to get the names of those pages.

I call the function `fetchLikeData()` exactly after a successful login.
Is something wrong with the way I manipulate the JSON object?
Because my string array likeTitles[] stays null.

```
public void fetchLikeData()
{

        final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                    {
                        Log.v("JSON1",object.toString());

                        //Handling JSON object
                        try {

                            String likeID;
                            String likeCategory;
                            String likeName;
                            int likeCount;

                            //Getting likes object
                            JSONObject jsonObjectLikes = object.getJSONObject("likes");

                            //Put likes data into a JSON array
                            JSONArray jsonArrayLikes = jsonObjectLikes.getJSONArray("data");

                            //Create FacebookLike array to populate with data
                            likeList = new ArrayList<FacebookLike>();

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayLikes.length(); i++)
                            {

                                //Store every single like in a JSON object
                                JSONObject jsonObjectLike = jsonArrayLikes.getJSONObject(i);

                                //Get id and category and name for every like
                                likeID = jsonObjectLike.getString("id");
                                likeCategory = jsonObjectLike.getString("category");
                                likeName = jsonObjectLike.getString("name");
                                likeCount = jsonObjectLike.getInt("likes");


                                Log.v("likeID", likeID);
                                Log.v("likeCategory", likeCategory);
                                Log.v("likeName", likeName);
                                Log.v("likeCount", Integer.toString(likeCount));

                                if (likeCount>100 && count<10) {
                                        //Add like info to the list

                                        likeTitles[i] = likeName;
                                        count++;

                                }


                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "likes{id,category,name,location}");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Firstly you have to add the permission before login.

LoginButton  loginButton.setReadPermissions("email,publish_actions,user_friends,user_likes");

// Initialize the ArrayList globally:

public List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

// And use the following code to retrieve data

```
public void fetchLikeData(){

        GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                login_result.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject json_object,
                            GraphResponse response) {

                        try {

                            JSONArray posts = json_object.getJSONObject("likes").optJSONArray("data");
                            Log.e("data1",posts.toString());
                            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                                String id = post.optString("id");
                                String category = post.optString("category");
                                String name = post.optString("name");
                                int count = post.optInt("likes");

                                Log.e("name -", id+" name -"+name+ " category-"+ category+" count-"+count);

                                list.add(name);

                                // Added All name of pages in the list
                        }

                        Log.e("list",list.toString());
                        // Print Array list


                        } catch(Exception e){

                        }

                    }
                });
        Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
        permission_param.putString("fields", "likes{id,category,name,location,likes}");
        data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
        data_request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed that you get the posts from each page or am I wrong?
All I want is the names of the pages and then put them in a string array.
Should I add the following?
JSONArray likes =object.getJSONObject("likes").names();

Comment: I have edited answer with your requriment. If you want to know [how to integrate and login with facebook](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-facebook-integration-and-login/) visit it